# Text width phaser.js

Tags: javascript, phaser

Does phaser have any function that returns the width of the text or if not, how can I center text inside rectangle I've drawn?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just `Text.width`. Text objects have most the same properties as Sprites, so you can set their anchor, rotate them, etc.